# How to scrape dynamically "changing" data with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open("http://yourwebsite", function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {
        page.evaluate(function(){
            document.getElementById("firstName").value = "John";
            document.getElementById("lastName").value = "Doe";

        });
    }
phantom.exit();
});
```

So when using phantomjs to do web scraping of data that is constantly being updated by a script, let's say scores or stock prices for example. How would you create a persistent open browser state to collect this data without having to use a `setInterval/Timeout` to call `page.open("http://yourwebsite", function(status) {}` in a loop?

Is there an api call in phantonjs that actually performs like a real browser in a headless state? or am I just reloading pages and reading the static data from each reload?

Comment: you shouldn't have to reload at all. Why not use intervals to re-query the DOM? this should work perfectly. PhantomJS is a real browser btw.

Comment: So inside the callback function, I can setinterval on the specific element and not have to reopen the page?... make this your answer so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to reopen the page, at most you'll have to manually track  state across `setInterval()` calls to determine *when* to exit:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("http://yourwebsite", function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);

    if(status === "success") {
        var count = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            if (count++ === 5) {
                //You will need to figure out when to exit!!!!
                phantom.exit();
            }
            page.evaluate(function(){
                document.getElementById("firstName").value = "John";
                document.getElementById("lastName").value = "Doe";
            });
        }, 5000/*5 SECONDS*/);
    } else {
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```